# Why Object.defineProperty not working in iframe

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to define property of canvas, but it does not work from iframe. How I can fix my code? Thanks!

```
<html>
    <head></head>
<body>
        <iframe id="canvas-iframe" sandbox="allow-same-origin"></iframe>
        <script>
            const getContext = HTMLCanvasElement.prototype.getContext;
            Object.defineProperty(HTMLCanvasElement.prototype, "getContext", {
                value: function () {
                    let r = getContext.apply(this, arguments);
                    console.log("It's work");
                    return r;
                }
            });

            var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas-iframe").contentDocument.createElement("canvas");    
            var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d")
        </script> 
</body>
</html>
```

[My code](https://jsbin.com/jeqacacale/edit?html,js,console)

Comment: `Object.defineProperty == window.Object.defineProperty`, and iframes have a different `window`. you would have to get the contentWidow of the iframe (once it loads), then mod that.

Comment: Thanks. It's work! Maybe there is a universal solution? Or I should find all the frames and assign each window?

Comment: afaik, you can't modify natives on all `window`s at once, you have to mod each one. Might be easier to just inject a script into each frame that does what you need, maybe even from a dataURL... that way, you don't have to have the long prefixes and your original code would work...

Comment: You need to modify the prototype of `iframe.contentWindow.HTMLCanvasElement`, not of `self.HTMLCanvasElement`.